# Is it possible to intersect Request.Headers with another list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, httprequest, visual-studio-2017

I am attempting to intersect a list of headers:

```
var validHeaders = Request.Headers.ToArray().Intersect(ValidHeaders.List);
```

Where ValidHeaders are defined as:

```
public static class ValidHeaders
{
    public static readonly IList<string> List = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>
    (new List<string>
    {
        "Content-Type",
        "DataServiceVersion",
        "MinDataServiceVersion",
        "Accept",
        "If-Match",
        "If-None-Match",
        "Prefer"
    });
}
```

**How do I intersect HttpRequestHeaders list with another list?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning all the headers and their values of headers whose `Key` (Header name) is found in the `ValidHeaders.List`

```
var validHeaders = Request.Headers.Where(header => ValidHeaders.List.Any(k => string.Equals(k, header.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
```

This can be added as an extension method to the static `ValidHeader` class

```
public static class ValidHeaders {
    public static readonly IList<string> List = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(new List<string>
    {
        "Content-Type",
        "DataServiceVersion",
        "MinDataServiceVersion",
        "Accept",
        "If-Match",
        "If-None-Match",
        "Prefer"
    });

    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, IEnumerable<string>>> GetValidHeaders(this HttpRequestMessage request) {
        var validHeaders = request.Headers.Where(header => ValidHeaders.List.Any(k => string.Equals(k, header.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)));
        return validHeaders;
    }
}
```

And used

```
var validHeaders = Request.GetValidHeaders();
```

Comment: we dont need a case-insensitive comparison?

Comment: well in this case the values in List match cases used in HttpRequestHeader. easy to modify code to ignore case

Comment: indeed, but will the headers' case ever be different?

Comment: Yes it is possible that a hand crafted request can have headers with different case.